# How do I access a variable in a generic class

Tags: c#, class, variables, generics

I'm getting a CS1061 error on with following code at `Console.WriteLine(item.type)` which seems simple enough to me.

Can anyone help me here please?

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LocalPage lp = new LocalPage();
            lp.Put();
        }
    }
    public class LocalDataFolder
    {
        public LocalDataFolder() { }
        public int type;
    }
    public class PicturePage<T>
    {
        public List<T> folders = new List<T>() { };
        public void Put()
        {
            foreach (T item in folders)
                Console.WriteLine(item.type); 
        }
    }
    public class LocalPage : PicturePage<LocalDataFolder>
    {
        public LocalPage()
        {
            folders.Add(new LocalDataFolder());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the message that comes with the error? You didn't mention that. You also didn't tag your question with the programming language you are using. I did look up the CS1061 message online (which you can do as well) and it says that the *type' does not contain a definition for 'member'*. That tells me that your `item` doesn't have a member called `type`, so `item.type` is an invalid reference to a member (`type`) that doesn't exist. You need to check the type of `item` and understand what members it has.

Comment: generics are not dynamic types. see answers on constrainning  the type.

Answer (score 3):

An unconstrained generic can only access methods or properties available on the `object` type.

A constraint, such as the one specified by @Mark-Yisri, enables access to methods and properties matching the constraint, but then limits the types allowed to be used with the generic type or method.

This constraint restricts the generic to working with LocalDataFolder or classes that inherit from LocalDataFolder, but enables access to methods and properties available in an object of type LocalDataFolder.

```
public class PicturePage<T> where T : LocalDataFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the `item.type` correct? In Java generics cannot have any fields associated with them, you would have to use `T extends LocalDataFolder`. Not sure what the relevant syntax is in C#.

Try this:

```
public class PicturePage<T> where T : LocalDataFolder
{
    public List<T> folders = new List<T>() { };
    public void Put()
    {
        foreach (T item in folders)
            Console.WriteLine(item.type); 
    }
}
```